# ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed

Tags: java, spring

I am struck with this error from 2 days. Any help?

```
 ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFilter' defined in file [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/portal/WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-security.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 1 of type [com.xxx.cloud.common.sessionclient.retrievers.SessionRetrievalStrategy]: : Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xxx/abc/realm_id' is defined: not found in JNDI environment; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Injection of resource dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'xxx/abc/realm_id' is defined: not found in JNDI environment
```

Code:

```
@Resource(mappedName = "xyz/abc/realm_id")
private String assId;

@Bean
public String assId() {
    return assId;
}
```

applicationContext-Security.xml where the bean is defined, but it doesnt pick up

```
<beans:bean id="xyz/abc/realm_id" class="com.xxxxxxxx.SecurityConfig">
            <beans:property name="assId" value="123456789"/>
        </beans:bean>
```

We cannot use tomcat context.xml.

Comment: Have you tried `jee:jndi-lookup` instead of `bean` element?

Comment: I am using tomcat server. I have to avoid jee:jndi-lookup

Comment: I think the way you are using it is just wrong. Why can't you just use jndi-lookup? It is the convenient way to do JNDI lookups in spring?

Comment: How do I set value for the same? I have to use properties and not tomcat context.xml

Comment: Than why are sour trying to inject via `@Resource`? This is supposed for JNDI lookups